# Не могу импортировать модуль javafx.scene.media в проект

Tags: javafx, mediaplayer, library

Коллеги, доброго времени суток!

Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Я уже всю голову сломал, не могу понять, в чем подводный камень.

В Идее создаю стандартный базовый демо-проект HelloApplication на javafx. Все работает, окошко с надписью выскакивает, проблем нет. Пытаюсь импортировать в данный проект javafx.scene.media. И не могу. Другие библиотеки javafx при этом импортируются без проблем.

Пробовал под ноль сносить в проекте все библиотеки и заново подключать библиотеки javafx. Картина не поменялась. Именно данный пакет не импортируется javafx.scene.media.

Что я делаю не так?

[image: Пакет не импортируется]

[image: Библиотеки fx перезалиты]

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь импортировать не определенный класс, а всю библиотеку целиком. Для того чтобы это сделать пишите `import javafx.scene.media.*;`, если вам нужнен какой-то определенный класс, указывайте его: `import javafx.scene.media.Media;`, `import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;` и т.д.